# Python Sqlalchemy access many to many data in view

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, jinja2

I have a many to many relation. Inserting data is no problem, but I dont know how to correctly get the data in jinja2 / view. I have a working approach but it feels like a workaround.

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    children_PostBelongsCategory = relationship("PostBelongsCategory")
    # etc.

class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    category_name = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    # etc.
```

Many to Many relation of `Post` and `Category`:

```
class PostBelongsCategory(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'postbelongstocategories'
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('posts.id'), primary_key=True)
    category_id = Column(Text, ForeignKey('categories.category_name'), primary_key=True)  
    child = relationship("Category")
```

The way I am doing it right now is query all `Post` items, query all `PostBelongsCategory` items and then make two nested for loops with an if loop comparing the id's:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="post-item">
            <h1> {{ post.title }} </h1>
            <p> {{ post.description }} </p>
            {% for cat in categories %}
                {% if cat.post_id == post.id %}
                    <p> {{ cat.category_id }} </p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I think my approach could lead to performance issues if the tables are very large (but I am not sure here, maybe someone can help me here). Also as mentioned before my approach feels like a workaround. Is there a better way to get the data from many to many?

What I tried so far is using `lazyload`:

```
Post.query.options(lazyload('children_PostBelongsCategory')).order_by(desc("created_on")).all()
```

This gave no errors, but also nothing new. I am currently reading about join/load options but I am not sure whether I am on the correct path.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I was so close, just needed the correct syntax. Thank you very much, it works. If you answer the question I'll accept it. Also good to know that lazyload is default.

Comment: Also is it true that my approach would lead to performance issues compared to the correct one?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks!

Comment: Btw does your real association object have additional columns other than the foreign keys? If not, you could simplify your setup a bit and use it as a secondary table, removing the need to go through 2 relationships to access the categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the defined ORM relationship for accessing related objects:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    ...
            {% for assoc in post.children_PostBelongsCategory %}
                <!-- do something with assoc.child here -->
            {% endfor %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Relationships are by default lazy loading, so there's no need to pass that option in your case. Your original approach is a bit like a manual nested loop join, but performed in Python, and might have inferior performance, if you have a lot of categories.

In practice lazy loading means that each relationship attribute access will issue a new SELECT in order to fetch the related objects. If you have many posts, this can become an issue. A solution is to eager load related objects in the same query that fetches the posts. A good primer to that is [joined eager loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading):

```
# Note the chaining in the passed options
Post.query.\
    options(joinedload('children_PostBelongsCategory')
            .joinedload('child')).\
    order_by(Post.created_on.desc()).\
    all()
```